# AWS Cloudformation: Set up ECS cluster with parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

According to the [official CF/ECS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-cluster.html), the ECS Cluster resource takes **no parameters at all** (!).

However, when setting up a cluster via AWS console, there are several (and critical!) parameters that one defines (e.g. no of instances, instance types etc etc)

How is it possible to define a cluster properly via CloudFormation?

Why such a huge discrepancy between CF and console on this resource?

Answer (score 2):

The ECS-cluster is only a logical namespace inside the ECS service. The actual EC2 instances on which the tasks are going to run are not managed by ECS itself, these have to be created separately.

What the ECS console wizard does is launch a Cloudformation template that contains both the ECS-cluster definition and the EC2 instances. The template contains the parameters that you see in the console wizard.

You might be able to reuse this template, otherwise use a Cloudformation template like below. This uses the [Amazon ECS-optimized AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) which contains all the applications that you need.

```
  AppServerLaunchConfig:
   Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
   Properties:
     ImageId: "ami-c91624b0"
     # instance role must have permissions to join ECS cluster
     IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfile
     KeyName: !Ref KeyName
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     SecurityGroups: [ !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup ]
     UserData:
       Fn::Base64: !Sub |
         #!/bin/bash
         # join cluster with this name
         echo ECS_CLUSTER=myclustername >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config           

   AppServerGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      MaxSize: 2
      MinSize: 0
      DesiredCapacity: 1
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref AppServerLaunchConfig
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref SomeSubnetId

   ECSCluster:
     Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
     DependsOn: AppServerGroup
     Properties:
       ClusterName: myclustername
```

Answer (score 0):

In CF you have `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition` and `AWS::ECS::Service` to take care of cluster configuration. Remeber that AWS console is an interactive tool and CF is for [IaC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_Code).

**Update to address some concerns rised by OP**

There are some cluster parameters not configurable by CF templates. CF documentation on `AWS::ECS::CLUSTER` states that:

> The AWS::ECS::Cluster resource creates an Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS) cluster. This resource has no properties; use the Amazon ECS container agent to connect to the cluster. For more information, see Amazon ECS Container Agent in the Amazon Elastic Container Service Developer Guide.

Comment: Yes but instance number and type are cluster (and not task/service) specific parameters; where should these be configured? these have to do with Infrastructure as well!

Answer (score 0):

From that it seems taking into account some [reference templates](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/ECS/EC2LaunchType/clusters/public-vpc.yml) provided by `AWS` itself, the cluster bootstrapping process when **not** done via the AWS console, is a highly manual, tedious, error-prone, unmaintanable and laborious process based on a series of `cfg-init` / `user-data` scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that setting up an ami, which is not one of Amazon-Linux 'magic' distros, is pain. Although the following snippets I came up with, work with Ubuntu (indentation might be not 100% accurate).

Ellipses mean, of course, that parts of template are missing, but you should get the picture anyways. Good luck!

```yaml
Resources:
  MyCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: myCluster
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          files:
          # refer to 
          # docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html
            /etc/ecs/ecs.config:
              content: !Sub
                ...
                ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg
                ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA=...
                ...
                ECS_CLUSTER=${MyCluster}
          commands:
            01_ecs_agent_run:
              command: !Sub |
                docker run --name ecs-agent \
                --detach=true \
                --restart=on-failure:10 \
                --volume=/var/run:/var/run \
                --volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log \
                --volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data \
                --volume=/etc/ecs:/etc/ecs \
                --net=host \
                --env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config \
                amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
    Properties:
      ...
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          ...
          # install docker here
          # https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
          ...
          # follow the steps 1-7 from aws docs
          # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html;
          ...
          # install aws helpers
          apt-get install python-pip -y
          pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
          ln -s /usr/local/init/ubuntu/cfn-hup /etc/init.d/cfn-hup
          systemctl enable cfn-hup
          /usr/local/bin/cfn-init --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource MyInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
```

**Answer update:**

The above can be achieved with console by adding UserData when launching the instance.